# How style two class css with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a css style without using the file.css but using file.js then via jquery, can you help me?

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){
      $( ".ytp-gradient-top", ".ytp-gradient-bottom" ).css({  
          "border": "3px solid red" 
      )};
  )};
```

Comment: You're going to have to set `border-width`, `border-style`, and `border-color` separately.

Comment: Did you mean `$( ".ytp-gradient-top,ytp-gradient-bottom" ).css` ?

Comment: jQuery will only touch the first selector (and silently ignore the second), so you should combine yours into one like freedomn-m suggested (add the dot before ytp-gradient-bottom, though).

Comment: Right also you should be passing just *one* string, with both class selectors separated by a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( ".ytp-gradient-top, .ytp-gradient-bottom" ).css( 
      "border" , "3px solid red" 
);
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as what the OP has. jQuery allows an object to be passed to set more than one property, but it's fine to just set one.

Comment: Other than removing document.ready, can you explain what you've done?  If it is just removing document.ready, can you explain why you think that would be the answer?

Comment: @freedomn-m op added the property as an object, not comma separated arguments. Also his brackets look like they don't match. My removal of 'document.ready' was not meaningful -- it's not `document.ready` that is under question, that part of the code is not relevant

Comment: @freedomn-m i also changed the css selector to 1 string

Comment: Just tested and can confirm this answer works as it should.

Comment: @TKoL https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
  $( document ).ready(function(){

      $( ".ytp-gradient-top, .ytp-gradient-bottom" ).css({

          "border" : "3px solid red" 

    )};

)};
```

You need to add quotes around the selectors and comma. See the jQuery API: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/